# Unity's HLSL/Cg preprocessor works wrong way?

Tags: c++, c, unity-game-engine, hlsl, preprocessor

When I implemented macro in HLSL in Unity project, I encountered a weird problem.

```
#define read(name) read2(TYPEOF(name), name)
#define TYPEOF(name) typeof_ ## name
#define read2(t, name) TYPEOF_READ(t, name)
#define TYPEOF_READ(a, b) a ## _read(b) 
#define typeof_X float

read(X);
```

I expected this expands like below.

```
float_read(X);
```

But Unity says

> Undeclared identifier 'typeof_X_read'.

Are there some implementation differences between HLSL/Cg preprocessor and one of general C?
Of course I've checked

```
gcc -E
```

worked like I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is because the HLSL preprocessor does a few things differently than the C preprocessor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

**EDIT:** In this case, it seems that it may be a compiler bug. The macros expand properly and can be tested here: https://tryhlsl.azurewebsites.net/

```
#define read(name) read2(TYPEOF(name), name)
#define TYPEOF(name) typeof_ ## name
#define read2(t, name) TYPEOF_READ(t, name)
#define TYPEOF_READ(a, b) a ## _read(b) 
#define typeof_X float

void float_read(float) {}

struct PSInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

PSInput VSMain(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    float X;
    read(X);

    PSInput result;

    return result;
}

float4 PSMain(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.color;
}
```

Comment: >>the pasted tokens must be valid tokens. Does this cause such a difference? I can't understand what 'valid' means in the context.

Comment: The invalid token in the link is `x4`. However, in your case, I don't see any invalid tokens. It seems that it simply does not pickup that `typeof_X` has been defined as `float`. It is possible that this is a compiler bug (depending on the card, graphics driver and version of DirectX).

Comment: It does indeed seem to be a compiler bug, which in turn may be a combination of your card, graphics driver, version of DirectX. You can test your code here: https://tryhlsl.azurewebsites.net/